# Is there a way to say my father's mother's mother concisely?

Tags: kinship-terms

In the English language there's the option to say my paternal grandmother, but does such a convention work further back?  For instance my paternal maternal great-grandmother?

Comment: There are no generic shortcuts. The more distant a relation is, the more syllables it will take to identify them unambiguously in English. I'm not sure this would be brief even in languages with a richer set of kinship terms relative to English's paucity.

Comment: @Dan: I was quite surprised to discover last night that among those countries that tolerate marriage between "first cousins", at least *some* distinguish between the child you fathered marrying your *brother's son* (often permitted) or your *sister's daughter* (often discouraged). My mission tonight will be to investigate whether this has any implications for [birth defects due to inbreeding](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/health/children/11723308/First-cousin-marriages-in-Pakistani-communities-leading-to-appalling-disabilities-among-children.html), which are rife in the UK today.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Does the reason for the difference in acceptability have anything to do with "mother's baby, father's maybe"?  That is, you can't be 100% sure that your brother is the father of your broher's son?

Comment: I would assume @ab2 is correct. A man marrying his "daughter" to his brother-from-the-same-mother increases the chance that his "grandchildren" will carry some of his DNA. Mom, on the other hand, already *knows* that her daughter's children will carry her DNA, so there's no percentage in marrying her to Mom's brother. Of course, marrying a *son* to a sister's daughter would be good for either Mom or Dad, genetic-heritage-wise, hence first-cousin marriage.

Comment: I know that in Norwegian you can say something like "farmormor", and I suspect other languages have similar things.  English does not have such contractions, but "father's mother's mother" is the same thing, only longer.

Comment: The link supplied by FumbleFingers refers to certain communities among a particular ethnic group. Neither cousin marriage nor resultant birth defects are 'rife' among the general population of the UK.

Comment: You could just say:  my father's mother's mother.

Answer (score 0):

When the family becomes that extended, it no longer is appropriate to be so specific. (Formally)

If your conversation requires this level of specificity, you would clarify it with reference to the entire line if necessary. Otherwise, "Distant Grandmother", or "Ancient Grandmother" covers all grandmothers more distant than "Great Grandmother"

A general rule, is that if you couldn't have met her, she doesn't have a specific title in relationship to you. Even the royals referenced these relationships as commoners would. After the 4th generation, they would use the official title, rather than the filial title.